# Swap Scripts via a Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object which contains scripts for splines. I want to be able to change the splines with a trigger.

```
 void OnTriggerEnter (Collider tag)
 {
     if(gameObject.tag == "Player")
     {
         JousterMove jm = gameObject.GetComponent <JousterMove> ();

         jm.spline = ??????????
     }
 }
```

It's the `???????` I cannot figure out. I want to swap out the splines to move the character along a different path, but I cannot figure out the syntax to make that happen.

I don't think this is so much a spline question as a syntax question concerning how to manipulate public values within the Inspector in Unity. I've devoured a bunch of tutorials and not seen an answer yet.

Please do not reference the Catlike Coding tutorial as that's where I learned about splines and coding them, but he doesn't explain how to switch splines.

Comment: Your doing it wrong, if its just a path swapping, your splines should be stored in a variable of a `Component`, they shouldn't be the `Component` itself

Comment: @LOLslowSTi can you please elaborate the thought?

Comment: Instead of swapping out the entire `JouserMove` `Component`, you should be swapping only a single field such as `JousterMove.Path`, which contains your entire new path

Comment: I think you should reverse your "please do not reference the Catlike Coding tutorial" statement--it's actually quite useful to know what your code's like. You should also link it. A few questions about your issue: do you have the other spline defined as a component somewhere else? Or is it on the same game object as the first spline?

Comment: @31eee384 I made that comment because I asked this question on the unity boards and that tutorial is where people pointed, which isn't helpful because that's where I learned splines and I know for a fact he doesn't cover changing splines. The other spline is its own object in the Hierarchy pane. As is the first spline which is then dragged into the spline field in the Inspector pane for the player object.

Comment: Do any of the answers [on this Unity Answers post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/530178/) work for you? In short, Unity doesn't support this. If those answers don't work, either you need to understand your code well enough to make it so you are moving some custom object rather than a `Component` derivative, or you need to give us more info to help you through that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to answer this without knowing the API of JousterMove, but my best guess with this limited information would be...

```
 void OnTriggerEnter (Collider tag)
 {
     if(gameObject.tag == "Player")
     {
         JousterMove jm = gameObject.GetComponent <JousterMove> ();

        jm.spline = new Spline(somePoint, someOtherPoint, someAnchor, someOtherAnchor);
     }
 }
```